# Make form invalid when select option select to 0 value

Tags: angular

```
<select name="tenure" 
        formControlName="tenure" 
        class="form-control" 
        (change)="TenureChange($event.target.value)">
     <option value="0">--select--</option>
     <option *ngFor="let tenur of ddltenure">{{tenur}}</option>
</select>
<span class="validation-block" 
       *ngIf="!planmodeForm.get('tenure').valid && planmodeForm.get('tenure').touched">
              Please select tenure
</span>
```

in my component

```
this.planmodeForm = new FormGroup({
        'planmode': new FormControl(null, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern(this.planmodePattern)]),
        'tenure': new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
        'maxstudents': new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
        'maxusers': new FormControl(null, Validators.required),
        'notificationconf': new FormArray([])
    });
```

I want to make my form invalid when slect option is changed to 0

Comment: I am using angular 5 reactive form method.

Comment: `value="0"` should be `value=""`

Comment: Thank you for the answer @Igor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`value="0"` should be `value=""` for the `required` validation to work.

Comment: am using reactive form method. Any modification in component file